# Increase scroll speed in Okular only

Tags: gnome, qt, okular

Okular scrolls (at least when using two-finger touchpad scrolling) much slower than most other applications on my computer (in particular evince).

Is there some way to increase the scrolling speed just of Okular, or alternatively for all Qt applications?

This is on Ubunutu 21.10 (using GNOME 40.5).